pgTable from drizzle relations many to many is deprecated
Following the docs to create a many to many relation it suggests to create a junction or join table. The ts deprecation error is below.
@deprecated — This overload is deprecated. Use the other method overload instead.
The suggested code is as follows:
export const usersToGroups = pgTable(
  'users_to_groups',
  {
    userId: integer('user_id')
      .notNull()
      .references(() => users.id),
    groupId: integer('group_id')
      .notNull()
      .references(() => groups.id),
  },
  (t) => ({
    pk: primaryKey({ columns: [t.userId, t.groupId] }),
  }),
);

The error occurs when trying to generate the primary key.
I followed all the docs looking for a suggestion. I tried delving into the generated types to find the error too.

When there's no explanation on docs, release note is where we should go.
Check this out: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/releases/tag/0.36.0

